# document.friendform1.friends[i].checked not working when there is only one element in checkbox array

Tags: php, javascript, html

document.friendform1.friends[i].checked is not working when there is only one element in checkbox array. If there are more than one element in checkbox array than it is working fine

my html and php code is

```
 $x=0;
foreach($result as $row)
{
    if($x==0)
    {?>
        <div class="invite-friends-con">
    <?php 
    }else{?>
        <div class="invite-friends-con" style="margin-left:70px;">
    <?php 
    }?>
    <div class="invite-friends-con-img">
       <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>Profile_images/<?php echo $row->vchPicture?>" width="48" height="39" align="absmiddle" />
    </div>
    <span><?php echo $row->vchFirstName?></span><input type="checkbox" name="friends[]"  style="margin-top:10px" value="<?php if($row->intFriendID==$this->session->userdata('user_id')){ echo $row->intMemberID;}else{ echo $row->intFriendID;}?>" id="friends"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="frnd[]" id="frnd" value="<?php echo $row->vchFirstName?>" />
    <?php if($x==1){$x=0;}else{$x++;}?>
<?php 
} ?>
```

and javascript code is:

```
 function addalfriend()
 {
   var str='';
   var str1='';

    var len=document.friendform1.friends.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
      if(document.friendform1.friends[i].checked==true)
       {
         if(str=='')
         {
           str=document.friendform1.friends[i].value;
           str1=document.friendform1.frnd[i].value;
         }
         else
         {
           str=str+","+document.friendform1.friends[i].value;
           str1=str1+","+document.friendform1.frnd[i].value;
         }
       }
    }
        document.getElementById('invite_1').value=str;
        if(str!='' && str1!=''){
            document.getElementById('invited').style.display="block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('invited').style.display="none";
        }
        document.getElementById('invited').value = str1;
        document.getElementById("low-high-div").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("events-input-bg2").value="";
        document.getElementById("events-input-bg3").value="";
        closemessage1();
        return false;

 }
```

So please someone let me know my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? and when are you calling this function addalfriend

Comment: I am trying to add checked checkboxes value to hidden field. and I am calling addalfriend on click of a button

Comment: Which button? And in which hidden field are you adding checked checkbox value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when there is one item return then array is not retuned element object is returned so you need to access it differently then
as

```
var len=document.friendform1.friends.length;
if(len>1)
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
  if(document.friendform1.friends[i].checked==true)
   {
     if(str=='')
     {
       str=document.friendform1.friends[i].value;
       str1=document.friendform1.frnd[i].value;
     }
.
.
.
}
else
{
  if(document.friendform1.friends.checked==true)
   {
     if(str=='')
     {
       str=document.friendform1.friends.value;
       str1=document.friendform1.frnd.value;
     }
   }
.
.
.

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rab but it doesn't enter for loop if there is only one element so should I keep else part out of for loop??

Answer (score 0):

You can try it simply like:

```
var len=document.friendform1['friends[]'].length || 1;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
  ...
    ...
   ...
}
...
...
...
```

Read [Why I can not get checkbox length while using it differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380030/why-i-can-not-get-checkbox-length-while-using-it-differently?noredirect=1#15380056)