# Why I can not get checkbox length while using it differently?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frm1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1[]"  value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1[]"  value="2"/>
</form>
<button class="test1">Test 1</button>

<form name="frm2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2[]"  value="1"/>
    <!--<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2[]"  value="2"/>-->
</form>
<button class="test2">Test 2</button>

<form name="frm3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk3[]"  value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk3[]"  value="2"/>
</form>
<button class="test3">Test 3</button>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$('button.test3').click(function (){
    alert(document.frm3.chk3.length);// Gives error: document.frm3.chk3 is undefined  
});

$('button.test2').click(function (){
    alert(document.frm2.chk2.length);// Outputs: undefined
});

$('button.test1').click(function (){
    alert(document.frm1.chk1.length);// Gives 2 as expected
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mgsvy/

If I can access a `form` by `name` and its `elements` then the **why** the above will give unexpected results?

Comment: If you use jQuery it's easier to use jQuery-specific methods for traversing the DOM tree.

Comment: You shouldn't be using 2 id's for the same control like you have with `chk1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `alert(document.frm3["chk3[]"].length);`

`document.frm3` uses name property to identify the elements, in your case the name of the check box is `chk3[]` so you need to use `document.frm3["chk3[]"]`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mgsvy/1/)

Comment: Ok, but what should I do for `frm2 chk2`?

Comment: `chk2[]` does not have a length property, because it is not an array (there is only one element with that name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.frm3['chk3[]'].length` or `document.getElementsByName` property
like this,

```
document.getElementsByName('chk1[]').length

document.getElementsByName('chk2[]').length

document.getElementsByName('chk3[]').length
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgsvy/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The waterproof way to do it, is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgsvy/2/

I removed the id's on the checkboxes, because you used the same id on multiple elements, which is why you got inconsistent behaviour. Because of the brackets in the name, you would have to use bracket notation to reference to that specific name.

If there is only one element with that name, it is stored as a node instead of a nodelist, which does not have a length property and `undefined` is returned.  The `|| 1` makes sure that you still get a proper output.

```
alert(document.frm2['chk2[]'].length || 1);
```

Comment: True, but what about `frm3 chk3[]`?

Comment: If you mean `frm3.chk3[]`, it would be interpreted as if you wanted an element of the array `frm.chk3`, which would not exist in your case. See `frm['chk3']` vs. `frm['chk3[]']`. They are two distinct things.